# Working on Linux command line

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, linux-terminal

How to create **domain users**,10 users in one domain,15 users in other domain in one linux machine using terminal.I thought of creating `sub domains` , but how to add users to that domain?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like a homework project.